# Possible to check if a VBAProject is clicked?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

VBA excel -- When a VBAProject is clicked or double-clicked, it will trigger a macro.  <<<<  Is there any way to do that?  How to determine if my VBAProject is clicked or double-clicked?  A user could open the VB Editor to click on other VBA projects, ok fine... but when the user clicks or double-clicks on my VBAProject, it will trigger a macro <<< Possible to do this?  How?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any macro could never be triggered by Click the VABProject.*

Sheet, Code, Workbook, User Form and Class are the  possible modules to RUN the macro.

Click event can be used as,

- Worksheet Click
- Cell Click
- Command Button Click
- Sheet TAB Click

To automate the macro you may think for,

- Workbook/Sheet/User Form, Load Event.
- Auto Open Event when Excel starts.
- RUN macro without load the Excel using VB Script file.

Comment: Glad to help you @SofiaEd, keep asking☺

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh!!  Sorry been busy, no time to reply, but your answers are always helpful.  I learn something new from you every time.